# Interpolate Table from txt

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm fairly new to python programming and I'm trying to write a program that plots a graph from a txt file and interpolate the data later.

To get the data, I know that I can use:

`precos = np.genfromtxt('Precos.txt', delimiter=',')`

or

```
precos = sp.loadtxt("Precos.txt", delimiter=",")
```

And the data is something simple like:

```
1,  69.00

2,  69.00

3,  69.00

4,  69.00

5,  69.00

6,  69.00

7,  69.00

8,  79.00

9,  56.51

10, 56.51
```

I also know that I can use

```
plt.plot(precos)
```

To plot the graph but I don't how to interporlate. I saw that `sp.interpolate.interp1d` can help, but I am still unable to get my head around it.

----EDIT----

Ok, I tried a new approach, and now my code is almost done, but I still getting one error.

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Importando os dados numa matriz Nx2

M = sp.loadtxt('Precos.txt', delimiter=',')

## Construindo os vetores X e Y

x=np.zeros(len(M))
y=np.zeros(len(M))
for i in range(len(M)):
    x[i] = M[i][0]
    y[i] = M[i][1]

##Grahp Plot

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("Fone de Ouvido JBL com Microfone T100A - Fevereiro 2017")
plt.xlabel("Dia")
plt.ylabel("Preco em R$")

##Interpolation

F = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
xn = sp.arange(0,9,0.1)
yn = F(xn)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xn, yn, '-')
plt.show()
```

But now I getting: **ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.**

Any ideas?

Comment: You first need to decide which kind of interpolation you want: linear, polynomial, rational, or other? Linear, which uses the line segment between two consecutive points, is simple enough to do on your own without any extra modules, but the others are more difficult.

Comment: I'm interested in Linear and polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

`sp.interpolate.interp1d` generates a function that you can reuse to interpolate the original data at intermediate points. Here's some specific code to breathe some life into it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

data = np.array([[1,  69.00],
[2,  69.00],
[3,  69.00],
[4,  69.00],
[5,  69.00],
[6,  69.00],
[7,  69.00],
[8,  79.00],
[9,  56.51],
[10, 56.51]])

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

# Define an interpolation function
interpolation_function = interpolate.interp1d(x,y,kind='linear')

# Define intermediate points to interpolate at, and print the result
xi = [1, 1.5, 2.5, 9.5]
print(interpolation_function(xi))
```

gives the result:

```
[ 69.    69.    69.    56.51]
```

Comment: Is there a way to not use the intermediate points? Other line than sp.interpolate.interp1d. And I need the graph interpolation

Comment: Drawing straight lines between defined input points is linear interpolation at the intermediate points between the defined input data. This linear interpolation is the only kind built into plt.plot. If you want a smooth curve, you should interpolate over dense intermediate points yourself, using something like `kind='cubic'` in the interpolation function. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Actually, my teatcher asked me do to this: Write a code that reads a .txt file that is a table with price/day of some product. And after plot the graph, it has to interpolate the data...It lacks some information, so I'm kinda lost.